# React - Wrapping all components in redux provider with store injection, Multi page app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have created an hoc which looks like

```js
const withStore = Component => {
  const storeWrapper = props => (
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
      <Component {...props } />
    </ReduxProvider>
  );

  return storeWrapper; 
};
```

Now all my separate components are wrapped by this(its multi page application) so that they can connect to same store, but that's not the case, one component is getting connected, changing with the incoming changes in props. But other components are totally disconnected not showing any change with data being changed in store.

Has anyone tried this approach earlier?

An example - if I have componentA and componentB, wrapped with this hoc.
Any store change from dispatch from componentA is getting reflected by componentA. Same for componentB. Main problem is when dispatch is from componentA and it is not getting read of componentB. vice-versa

Comment: Where are you getting `store` from? Is that a global variable or a module export? In the latter case, are all these pages being built by one build system or are they built independently? If independently, they might use the same file, but have several separate instances.

Comment: Store is coming from file which exports createStore(), all the pages are being built independently, can you elaborate on having separate instances?

Comment: Are your pages rendered on the server or in the browser?

Comment: In the browser @orel

Comment: Ok so as @phry wrote, you probably have one instance of your store per page.
What you could try to do to solve this is storing your store as a global variable (in the window object for instance) and injecting it in your ReduxProvider.

Comment: I have more instance of store on a single page, each wrapper component acts a mini react app with store injected in it, everything works like reducer updating store and dispatches, just the data update in store is not getting reflected by the component which are using useSelector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in @orel's comment, I resolved it by storing store in global variable.

In store.js file, to keep single instance everywhere, I added a condition

```html
if (!window.store) {
  window.store = store;
}
```

It works like charm now!!